# How can I populate another class function using PHP/Json object

Tags: php, json, class, object

so I have this JSON object, which I have converted into a PHP object, for example I can use *$apiobject->Response->DataItems* and get a response.

This is stored in a class called *returnjsonObject* with a public function called *getJsonObject*.

In the same file how can I populate another class using the data from this $apiobject into something like:

```
class Response
 {
   public $StatusCode;
 }
```

Then how can I for example echo out *$StatusCode*

Here is part of my file:

```
class Response
{
    public $StatusCode; //*I want this to equal $apiobject->Response->DataItems*
}

class returnjsonObject{
    public function getJsonObject()
    {

            echo"<pre>";
            $apiobject = json_decode($response);
            var_dump($apiobject->Response->DataItems);
            echo"<pre>";
    }
```

I've heard of using $this but I have to admit I don't understand it.

tl;dr I need to use *$apiobject* to populate *$StatusCode* using $*apiobject->Response->DataItems*

*Hope you understand my question :-)*

Comment: Have you studied the [OOP basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setter and getter

```
class Response{

   public $StatusCode;

    /**
    ...... 

    */


  public function __construct($attributes = Array()){
    // Apply provided attribute values
    foreach($attributes as $field=>$value){
      $this->$field = $value;
    }
  }

  function __set($name,$value){
    if(method_exists($this, $name)){
      $this->$name($value);
    }
    else{
      // Getter/Setter not defined so set as property of object
      $this->$name = $value;
    }
  }

  function __get($name){
    if(method_exists($this, $name)){
      return $this->$name();
    }
    elseif(property_exists($this,$name)){

      return $this->$name;
    }
    return null;
  }
}

$DataItems =$apiobject->DataItems;
$response = new Response($DataItems); 
echo $response->StatusCode;
```

Code not tested though. Learn more here.
http://www.beaconfire-red.com/epic-stuff/better-getters-and-setters-php

Answer (score 0):

I would first set all attributes in `Response` Class from `$apiobject` like this

```
<?php

class Response {

public $StatusCode;
/* more attributes
...
*/
public $Name

} //end of Response class
```

Then instantiate `Response` class and set attributes

```
$response = new Response();


  $response->StatusCode =$apiobject->DataItems->StatusCode;
  $response->Name=$apiobject->DataItems->Name;

/* Set all other properties
.......
*/

echo $respose->StatusCode; //output status code
```

Note: you use `$this` to make reference to a function or a property in the current class. i.e

```
Class Example {
public $name;
public function getThatName(){
 return $this->name; //we make reference to property `$name`
}
}
```

`$this` can only be use in a `Class`  or `Object` to reference a property or a function in itself.

You can not do this.

```
$example = new Example();
$this->name; //Wrong because you are not in `Example` class
```

Comment: Is there any other way I can do this, I have about 30 classes all with about 10 functions?

Comment: You can use getter and setter to achieve this.